# Activate dojo dgrid editor using keyboard

Tags: dojo, keyboard, editor, dgrid

Triggering edit mode in dojo dgrid with mouse event is easy. Here's what I have done:

```
editor({field: "checkNumber",label: "Check Number",editOn: "click"})
```

However, i want to trigger edit mode using keyboard. Specifically, i want to go into edit mode when I press the space key. How can I programmatically set a cell to 'edit mode' or 'non-edit mode'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add one or more `editor` columns to a grid, it makes the `edit` method available on the grid instance, which you can call with a cell element (or event referencing one) to programmatically shift focus to the editor for the cell.

Meanwhile, the `Keyboard` mixin has an `addKeyHandler` method which you can use to add handlers to respond to `keydown` events for particular keys.

Combining these two things, you can easily do the following to cause the grid to edit the focused cell when space is pressed:

```
grid.addKeyHandler(32, function (event) {
    grid.edit(event);
});
```

(`edit` should have no effect for cells in non-editor columns.)

An alternative solution could be to create an [extension event](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/on.html#extension-events) which triggers either on mouse click or on space keypress, and pass that to `editOn` instead of `'click'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var grdobj = dijit.byId("...");    
var editCell=grdobj.cell(rowNo, "checkNumber");
grdobj.edit(editCell);
```

Instead of `cell` function, you could make use of `right`, `left`, `up`, or `down` functions.

Hope that helps.